# html - How do I control elements placing

Tags: html, css

I have quickly scribbled the following page

[image]

But what I want to present is (Same thing different placing)

[image]

My original code was

```
<body>

  <p><b>My Title</b></p>

  <input type="radio" name="ReTranslate" id="TranslateByDate" value="ByDate" checked="checked">By Date:
    <input type="text" id="PackagesDate" /><br>
  <input type="radio" name="ReTranslate" id="TranslateByGuid" value="ByGuid">By Guid
    <input type="text" id="PackageGuid"> <br>
  <input type="radio" name="ReTranslate" id="TranslateByKey" value="ByKey">By Key:
    Field name <input type="text" id="PackageName">  Field number <input type="text" id="VersionNumber"> User name <input type="text" id="UserName"><br> 

  <br>
  <button type="button">ReTranslate</button>
</body>
```

How do I control elements placing?
Thanks.

Comment: Using [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

1. **Tables (Easy way)**

   Using tables, you can do this way:

   ```
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="radio" name="ReTranslate" id="TranslateByDate" value="ByDate" checked="checked">By Date:
       </td>
       <td><input type="text" id="PackagesDate" /></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   ```
2. **CSS**

   Add a `<ul></ul>`.

   ```
   <ul>
       <li><label for=""></label><input type="text"></li>
       <li><label for=""></label><input type="text"></li>
       <li><label for=""></label><input type="text"></li>
       <li><label for=""></label><input type="text"></li>
   </ul>
   ```

   And give the `label` some style like:

   ```
   label {display: inline-block; width: 75px;}
   ```

**Summary**

Usage of `<table>` tag for the layouts is not recommended for layouts. Usage of `<ul>` is good for semantics.

Comment: Probably someone feels tables have no place in HTML... There are many approaches to styling forms, tables are a valid option.

Comment: I have also explained which is the better method and stuff.

Comment: I haven't downvoted it, but AFAIK using tables to format not tabular data is a bad practice: it breaks accessibility and it doesn't keep structure and style separated.

Comment: @Simone-Cu Yes, I have also mentioned in the end about tables are not recommended... I don't understand why the downvote is still on. Anyways...

Comment: Exactly, that's why I haven't downvoted you ;) maybe someone saw this answer before your edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing br-tags in between the text 'By Key:', 'Field name', 'field number' and 'user name'. Then after that set a wanted margin on the left side of the texts. (margin-left:...px)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choices.

- place all the elements in a table to order and align them.
- You could also use DIVs and structure the inputs etc in different containers to get it aligned in the way you want